# Rails: Could not find bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I read infinitely many stackoverflow articles on missing gems in ruby but I still fail in solving the problem. Here is the situation:

```
nicolamac:Proj a$ rails new MyGreatApp
[...]
nicolamac:Proj a$ cd MyGreatApp/
[...]
nicolamac:MyGreatApp a$ bundle install
[...]
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But if I do:

```
nicolamac:MyGreatApp nicolagreco$ rails generate devise:install
```

I get

```
Could not find bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 in any of the sources
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try to install it by adding to your Gemfile:

```
gem "bcrypt-ruby"
```

an then run

```
bundle install
```